# Как задать тип для Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-типы

У меня есть Map:

```
  public unvisibleChildren = new Map<string, any>();
```

Пытаюсь задать тип вместо any:

```
  public unvisibleChildren = new Map<string, <T extends ITreeNode>>();
```

Но синтаксиси неверный, как правильно записать тип?

Comment: `<string, <T extends ITreeNode>>` -> `<string, T extends ITreeNode>`

Comment: Ругается так: `'?' expected.`

  `public unvisibleChildren = new Map<string, T extends ITreeNode>();`

Comment: Так просто `new Map<string, ITreeNode>()`. Зачем вам тут `extends`?

Comment: Потому что использую T  - это в классе `class A<T> {}`

Comment: Непонятно. Моё объявление не мешает класть в Map любых наследников ITreeNode.  Если вам нужно просто всегда T, то и используйте его Map<string, T> без всяких extends

Comment: А, ну собственно в конструкторе указывается конкретный тип. Поэтому никаких extends и т.д. тут нельзя писать. Можно писать _в определении_ переменной.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#generics